# How to embed a swf file and link it to another page using HTML?

Tags: html

I used

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" onmouseup="document.location='http://www.pageopensafterclick.com'" height=50 width=150>
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
  <param name="movie" value="myswffile.swf" />
</object>
```

to embed my swf file and link it to another page, but it is only working in Chrome, I.E., opera but not in Firefox. Can someone please tell me a code which works in all the browsers.
I would be so thankful.

Comment: what do you mean by link it to another page?

Comment: I meant that embedded .swf file when is clicked, it takes to another page. It's like making button with flash object, but using HTML not action script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div onmousedown="window.location.href='new_location'">
    <object>
        <param name="movie" value="3.swf">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <embed wmode=transparent allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" src="3.swf"></embed>
    </object>
</div>
```

Comment: Should the both 3.swf (first:param name="movie" value="3.swf"  second:  allowscriptaccess="always" src="3.swf")  be replaced by the original .swf file?

Comment: only 3.swf need to be replace with your original swf